# Using @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes, Deserialize an Object of Concrete Subclass Without Base Class and Type Information

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson, polymorphism

Using `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`, is it possible to deserialize an object of concrete subclass without type information?

Let's say I have an abstract `Animal` class:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat")
})
public abstract class Animal {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and a `Dog` subclass:

```java
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private String breed;

    public Dog() {
    }

    public Dog(String name, String breed) {
        setName(name);
        setBreed(breed);
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

I know I can instantiate a subclass object based on its parent class like this:

```json
{
    "type": "Dog",
    "name": "Jack",
    "breed": "shepherd"
}
```

```java
Animal deserializedDog = objectMapper.readValue(dogJson, Animal.class);
```

However, sometimes I would like to directly instantiate the subclass object without using the parent class:

```json
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "breed": "shepherd"
}
```

```java
Dog deserializedDog = objectMapper.readValue(dogJson, Dog.class);
```

The subclass object will be sent to an endpoint:

```java
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<Dog> sendDataToJms(
            @RequestBody Dog request, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) throws Exception {
    //...
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I got this if I ignore the `type` field: `JSON parse error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of ...`

Comment: You shouldn't get that when you're explicitly providing `Dog.class`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The JSON object is deserialized when passed as `@RequestBody Dog dog` under a `@PostMapping` annotation. However, I did provide the subclass name, won't it use `Dog.class` automatically?

Comment: *did provide the subclass name* Where/how? Your question does not contain sufficient detail to be answerable.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- I just found out directly providing a subclass won't work from [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/545).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution.

You need to enable `MapperFeature.USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_IMPL` in order to directly deserialize the object using concrete subclass without type information.

According to the official docs,

> `MapperFeature.USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_IMPL` is a feature that
> specifies whether the declared base type of a polymorphic value is to
> be used as the "default" implementation, if no explicit default class
> is specified via `@JsonTypeInfo.defaultImpl` annotation.

Next, you need to customise `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that converts the JSON request into a Java object as shown below.

```java
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_IMPL);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need create `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public JavaType handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext ctxt,
                                                        JavaType baseType,
                                                        TypeIdResolver idResolver,
                                                        String failureMsg)
                            throws IOException {
                        return baseType;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: When ObjectMapper did not see `type` field, it will try to `DeserializationProblemHandler` to handle missing type id, so you can add a new `DeserializationProblemHandler` to return `JavaType` you want, I'm using jackson 2.9.4, it has no `MapperFeature.USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_IMPL`